# Getting custom array contents back from Parse and sending them back to Parse

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

If you look here:

[image: screen shot]

You will see that I made a PFUser and added two new objects to it, a `sentItems` array and a `receivedItems` array. In my code I wanted to access those and append and change them, so I asked for help and got this:

```
var receivedItemsArr = PFUser.currentUser()!["receivedItems"] as? [Item]
var sentItemsArr = PFUser.currentUser()!["sentItems"] as? [Item]
```

`Item` is just an object that I made that I want the array to hold. This  doesn't work; it won't save, nor will it get for me what's in the array.

What Swift code do I need to write that would help me in the fact that it would make two new variables that would be the contents of those arrays from Parse, and that I would be able to save them back?

Comment: what are you trying to do

Comment: so I'm just trying to access the array, then set its data type, then access the stored information in the array and lastly save it

Comment: Wow ... are you trying to query the data from parse to an array

Comment: no. i don't think so i made a object called an array

Comment: and i just want the information from that array

Comment: I am sorry I still don't get it .... do you want to save an object to parse then retrieve it back

Comment: did you see the pic?

Comment: I did and I don't think it is a good idea to create those objects into the _User Class .... you should create a new class

Comment: ah but what about the code i gave someone else gave me it and it seems to work

Comment: how can i utilize it

Comment: lets not worry about the code they gave so far . Are you saving an object to class or trying to retrieve it

Comment: i really just want to access those arrays, then set the type, and give it some elements. lastly i want to be able to save the changes i made to that array back to parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you have create a new class named "Data".

```
var dummy = ["1","2"]
var dummy2 = ["3","4"]
var ObjectsToSave = PFObject(className: "Data")
var username = PFUser.currentUser()?.username
ObjectsToSave["receivedItems"] = dummy
ObjectsToSave["sentItems"] = dummy2
ObjectsToSave["username"] = username
    ObjectsToSave.saveEventually { (success:Bool, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
        // there is no error so object was save
        }
        else{
        // error
        }
    }
```

I think you are looking for something like that

Comment: you will use **PFQuery** and use the **findObjectInBackgroundwithBlock method**

Comment: so When I use parse i use the _User class more for my login and registering user create a new class to save a retrieve data ... glad i could help

Comment: but you didn't give an answer this is just a comment